# Java not equal to (!=) performance difference

Tags: java

I've always been taught in my first job as a Java Developer to avoid the use of "!=" but instead use an empty if clause then put the logic in the else:

```
//Bad:
if (x != null) {
   // logic
}

//Good:
if (x == null){
} else {
  // logic
}
```

Our lead developer's reasoning was to avoid an unnecessary bit-switch especially for simple logic like null checking.

I've been looking for sources that state this but I can't seem to find any. Is the empty if clause practice really a "best practice" or just a preference?

Comment: I don't know who taught you to use an empty `if` clause, but that's crap. All it does is make the code harder to maintain. (Why is the clause empty--is something supposed to go here?) There's certainly no performance difference.

Comment: How desperate is your performance gain to lose maintainability and/or readability?

Comment: Your lead developer ... wasn't very lead-y. I suspect more cargo cult-y.

Comment: It is very unlikely you'll notice any difference on using `==` or `!=`, the JVM optimizes the code in runtime, it does a lot of changes on the fly, even if there were a difference between then, if you used the not-optimized option, the JVM would replace it with the "optimized" one

Comment: I've been taught that do not leave a blank block code, and leave a comment such as `// do nothing because...` for it if you have to do. And the comment will force one to think again, is "do nothing" really right here?

Comment: CPU architectures typically have both jump if equal and jump if not equal variants of jump instructions.  For example, x86 has JE and JNE.  So there is no reason one should be any faster than the other.

Comment: I am asking this question because it's my second week in a new company and I've noticed them using "!=" regularly; compared to my last company when you would be informed to modify your logic when you do. The empty if clause was something I was taught/forced to use for 3 years. Now I'm with a new company, I just want to know if there is value for me to still keep using this practice. Thank you all for your input!

Comment: Ditch it.  The practice has no value.

Comment: By the way, this kind of code optimization through static analysis crap always irritates me.  The best practice is almost always to profile your code, either by manually instrumenting your code or with a profiler.  I have done a lot of C++ profiling, but don't have any direct experience profiling Java.  Maybe someone else can recommend a good Java profiler?

Comment: Micro optimisation in java is a waste of time. Code you write will run on a number of architectures each having slightly different behaviours towards things like this. Value in practices like this will be consistency of the code. Consistency can be important as people have a tendency to read what they expect rather than what is there.

Comment: Since there is virtually no performance difference between the two, I should just follow the current coding convention of the team. Thank you everyone for your insight!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IMO, this is a failed attempt at micro-optimisation.

Compile the code

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Object x = null;
    //Bad:
    if (x != null) {
       // logic
    }

    //Good:
    if (x == null){
    } else {
      // logic
    }
}
```

and check with `javap`

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String...) 
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_VARARGS
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: aconst_null
         1: astore_1
         2: aload_1
         3: ifnull        6
         6: aload_1
         7: ifnonnull     10
        10: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 9: 0
        line 11: 2
        line 16: 6
        line 20: 10

  }
```

[Both have a jump to another branch.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) There is no different in performance. IMO, the readability of your code suffers though.

> If x is null, blah, otherwise logic.

Comment: The key here is that both tests are implemented with a single JVM instruction:  `ifnull` for the `!=` case, `ifnonnull` for the `==` case.  There's no "bit-switch" step in the bytecode.  And since CPUs provide machine instructions for both positive and negative conditional jumps (such as JZ/JNZ on x86), a decent JIT should be able to avoid doing a "bit-switch" in the machine code too.

Comment: (If the use of `ifnull` for the `!=` case and vice versa seems counterintuitive, btw, remember that the bytecode is testing whether to jump *past* the `if` body without executing it.)